# VS2010 : Format a text box for currency

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, currency

I have check boxes selecting prices that go straight to the text box, how can I make it so it will display $ and two decimal places?

Code:

```
Dim total As Double
    If rb_s1.Checked = True Then
        txt_1.Text = "650.00"
    Else
        txt_1.Text = ""
        txt_1.Text = total
```

Answer (score 4):

use the formatcurrency() method.

```
  txt_1.text = formatcurrency(650.0)
```

EDIT: Please remember to use YOUR variable names and to not copy and paste sample code.  This format will work with your code when placed into your if statement.

Comment: Exactly as I showed you.  You pass your numeric value to it and it will format it as "money."  I.e it adds a dollar sign, formats it to 2 decimal places and returns that as a string.

Comment: it red underlines price and tells me to change it to some other options

Comment: Be more specific, please.  You didn't actually copy and paste my code, did you?  That's not going to work, it was an example.

Comment: i did copy your code, im not sure what to do with the curency actually i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric Datatypes have a ToString method you can call.
ToString() will just convert the numeric value to a string, but you can optionally
specify a format, by putting the format in as the method parameter.

I don't know all the formats, but I do know "C2" is currency with 2 decimal places.
For example, in your posted code:

```
Dim total As Double
    If rb_s1.Checked = True Then
        txt_1.Text = "650.00"
    Else
        txt_1.Text = String.Empty 'String.Empty is just a more precise way than ""
        txt_1.Text = total.ToString("C2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution how to convert to Currency I ok

*

1. dim test as string
2. test="1000"
3. txtBalance.Text = CDbl(result).ToString("#,##0.00")

*

Answer (score 0):

I found solution how to convert to Currency.
Try this :

```
Textbox1.Text = String.Format("{0:n2} $", CType(Textbox1.Text, Double))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function:

```
txt_1.text = Format("YOUR VALUE","#,##0.00")
```

The first param is your data. The second param indicates how you want that data formatted.